# I want to start a local server for Codeigniter-4 with "php spark serve" but get these errors

Tags: php, codeigniter, xampp

```
PS C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard-db> php spark serve
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to CodeIgniter\HTTP\URI::setScheme() must be of the type string, null given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard-db\vendor\codeigniter4\framework\system\HTTP\IncomingRequest.php on line 443 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard-db\vendor\codeigniter4\framework\system\HTTP\URI.php:749
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard-db\vendor\codeigniter4\framework\system\HTTP\IncomingRequest.php(443): CodeIgniter\HTTP\URI->setScheme(NULL)
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard-db\vendor\codeigniter4\framework\system\HTTP\IncomingRequest.php(207): CodeIgniter\HTTP\IncomingRequest->setPath('', Object(Config\App))
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard-db\vendor\codeigniter4\framework\system\HTTP\IncomingRequest.php(169): CodeIgniter\HTTP\IncomingRequest->detectURI('REQUEST_URI', ' http://localho...')
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard-db\vendor\codeigniter4\framework\system\Config\Services.php(589): CodeIgniter\HTTP\IncomingRequest->__construct(Object(Config\App), Object(CodeIgniter\HTTP\URI), '', Objec in C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard-db\vendor\codeigniter4\framework\system\HTTP\URI.php on line 749


Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to CodeIgniter\HTTP\URI::setScheme() must be of the type string, null given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard-db\vendor\codeigniter4\framework\system\HTTP\IncomingRequest.php on line 443 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard-db\vendor\codeigniter4\framework\system\HTTP\URI.php:749
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard-db\vendor\codeigniter4\framework\system\HTTP\IncomingRequest.php(443): CodeIgniter\HTTP\URI->setScheme(NULL)
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard-db\vendor\codeigniter4\framework\system\HTTP\IncomingRequest.php(207): CodeIgniter\HTTP\IncomingRequest->setPath('', Object(Config\App))
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard-db\vendor\codeigniter4\framework\system\HTTP\IncomingRequest.php(169): CodeIgniter\HTTP\IncomingRequest->detectURI('REQUEST_URI', ' http://localho...')
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard-db\vendor\codeigniter4\framework\system\Config\Services.php(589): CodeIgniter\HTTP\IncomingRequest->__construct(Object(Config\App), Object(CodeIgniter\HTTP\URI), '', Objec in C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard-db\vendor\codeigniter4\framework\system\HTTP\URI.php on line 749
```

Answer (score 10):

Sorry for the late answer. You probably solved it but this observation might help others too.

The problem may be due to the app.base URL in the .env file. Typing it such as 'localhost' or 'localhost:8080' will be incorrect, you should try typing 'http://localhost' instead.